# OSX with XAMPP: "imagegd2(): unable to open temporary file"

Tags: php, macos, tmp, gd2

I get "imagegd2(): unable to open temporary file" error message when I go to an image URL that is generated with imagegd2() like:

```
$image->make($data['path']);
$image->resize(100, null, true)->crop(70, 70);
// create response and add formated image
$response = Response::make($image->encode('png'));
// set content-type
$response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```

It is related with permissions and OSX, as in linux dev environment works fine.

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem, Mac OSx temporary folder is something similar to:
/var/folders/6l/zy7_vl5n5kq8wbv00bvzc15h0000gn/T/

Check your temporary folder in terminal:

```
echo $TMPDIR
```

An give read, write and execution permissions or 777 to that folder, not only 755:

```
chmod -R 777 [your_tmp_folder]
```

That's all!

Comment: You can also shorten this to `chmod -R 777 ${TMPDIR}`.

Comment: Getting this error after the commands mentioned in the answer and comment. chmod: Unable to change file mode on /var/folders/mn/3nv025hs4g16xt_spj91bhn80000gn/T/: Operation not permitted

Comment: Also getting "operation not permitted"